# new AmazonS3Client(credentials); is not working in AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am using aws lambda in java to resize images on s3

following code doesn't work inside lambda and neither it initialize s3client nor throws any error.

```
   AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("KEY", "PASSWORD");
        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

Can some one healp me out with this?

Comment: Is your `ACCESS_KEY` and `SECRET_KEY` correct?

Comment: Yes, I even generated a new one for this, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: What makes you say that it doesn't work? Have you tried to look at Lambda's log

Comment: Yes its there in the logs it prints all the lines logged before the above piece of code and stop printing logs after
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

Comment: Add the withRegion(Regions.yourKeyRegion) to the end of the credentials implementation. Also make sure that the keys and the s3 bucket are in the same region

Comment: First of all you don't need the AWS credentials. Your lambda is already deployed to AWS all you need is to provide access to your lambda to read write into s3., use IAM for that. Now since you already are running from AWS use the default Client  to create an s3 client. AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient() it will work.

Comment: This lambda that I deployed is not created with root user, I am using another IAM user for this purpose and that IAM user has AdministrationAccess, Do I have the need to give any other permission to this user to make it working for me?, Because the same lambda code is working with another aws account of mine which is created with root user.